# Screen turns off while watching video (VLC player & SM player)

Tags: video, display, vlc, smplayer

I'm on ubuntu 12.04 and I've already read similar questions and answers regarding this issue but none of them reported the same problem as I have.

The problem is that the screen turns off after 10 minutes while I watch a movie. No matter which player I use (VLC or SM), it still happens. It used to log me out too, but I changed the default setting as follows

[image: Display Setting]

After changing the setting, it doesn't log out automatically but it still turns off the screen. 
It seems like, system simply ignores the video players activities. How to solve this one (bug)?

Comment: Could try my answer here [How do I stop xscreensaver during movies play?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/445612/how-do-i-stop-xscreensaver-during-movies-play) but change xscreensave command line with `gnome-screensaver-command --deactivate`

Comment: Could you try this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/700163/26246 . Please, let me know your results? If you can't test it like you have changed that system/machine ...etc We may close this question as issue could not be reproduced.

Comment: Was any of the answers useful?

Comment: @davidbaumann: As far as I can remember, no none of them worked out for me. It's been a long time and I don't have that operating system installed anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Please do:

```
gconftool-2 --type bool --set /apps/gnome-screensaver/idle_activation_enabled "false"
```

That should keep the screen from turning off.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. Thanks anaway.

Comment: Hi can you tell how to prevent computer to sleep in xubuntu 14.04 64 bit

Answer (score 0):

Change your preferences in the player app. There is (the screwdriver icon) a tab for performance.  Make sure the check box for "Disable Screensver while playing" is checked.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same situation for SMPlayer, I did this. Go to:

*Options* → *Preferences* → in the left hand taskpane choose *General* → click on the *Video* tab under it, and click on the checkbox beside the option *Switch screensaver off*.

Clicked on Windows 7 platform, you can try it on Ubuntu, may be it would be the solution you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I run Caffeine.

```
sudo apt-get install caffeine
```

You have to remember to deactivate it or your screen will stay on.  I think I installed Caffeine Indicator as well which added an icon for ease of access.

Answer (score 0):

Change Blank Screen To Never..
[image]