# Trusty: Caffeine doesn't appear in panel after update

Tags: 14.04, panel, caffeine

There were a few ppa updates this morning, one of them was **Caffeine**.
It was working fine initially, it does show up in the start up applications list but does not show up in the panel.

I tried removing it and installing it but that didn't do anything.
I also figured it could have been my theme and icons, so I set it all to default to no avail.

I think it is **Caffeine 2.7**, not sure if I was on **2.6** or what. It was an official trusty ppa.

Anyone getting this issue?

I also noticed that Caffeine does function. I have my dim settings at 3 minutes, and when running a YT video in full screen it does not go to screen saver.
And when left idle, it goes to screen saver.

Comment: `dpkg -l | grep caffeine` should provide more informations on the package you have installed. You should also provide a link to the PPA you used. For managing PPA you may look at this : http://mrvaykadji.github.io/ppa-tool

Comment: It is 2.7, and the ppa is ppa.launchpad.net/caffeine-developers/ppa/ubuntu

Comment: There are two bug reports about this so far. This one: https://bugs.launchpad.net/caffeine/+bug/1310069 And one I just added requesting this functionality be re-added as a preference: https://bugs.launchpad.net/caffeine/+bug/1321750

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[The 2.7 release removes the user interface and manual operation](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/05/stop-ubuntu-sleeping-caffeine). Caffeine is now fully automatic: When the active window is full screen, Caffeine inhibits desktop idleness.

This has been changed in version 2.8 (released January 15th, 2015), which has:

- a `caffeine` program that works as v2.7: desktop idleness is prevented for full screen applications – fully automatic with no UI;
- a `caffeine-indicator` program that works as v2.6 and earlier: an icon is shown in the panel that enables/disables desktop idleness;
- a command `caffeinate`, that prevents desktop idleness for the duration of a command, e.g. `caffeinate steam` will prevent the screen saver while steam is running.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Although it would be nice if there was manual operation. Sometimes disabling screen saver when I'm just looking at a webpage for a long time is helpful. So long as it still works.

Comment: *"automatically enabled/disabled based on fullscreen activity only"* That's unfortunate, because people often want the screensaver disabled even when not fullscreen.

Comment: Fully automatic is really great!

Comment: Fully automatic Caffeine doesn't detect gamepad inputs. If this affects you, please visit https://bugs.launchpad.net/caffeine/+bug/1530544 & click "This bug affects you"

Answer (score 6):

As [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/469225/trusty-caffeine-doesnt-appear-in-panel-after-update/469323#469323) states, Caffeine 2.6 and up is fully automatic depending on if your window is fullscreen. The developers removed the manual toggle in the menu bar.

A new fork made by mildmojo called [Caffeine Plus](https://github.com/mildmojo/caffeine-plus) brings the manual toggle with the icon in the menu bar back. You can install it [manually with the .deb file](http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu/pool/main/c/caffeine-plus/) or via PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install caffeine-plus
```

Comment: The guys behind this ppa are amazing! So many useful tools...

Answer (score 5):

Fallback to version 2.6 by using another ppa for now. A [request](https://bugs.launchpad.net/caffeine/+bug/1321750) to enable the toggle functionality has been made.

```
sudo apt-get purge caffeine && sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:caffeine-developers/ppa
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:behda/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install caffeine
```

If it does not work then try following solution.

1. Install Caffeine from behda ppa. This will resolve dependencies and configure/installs icons, shortcuts...
2. Get the [source file](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/167583984/caffeine_2.6.2.tar.gz):

   ```
   tar -xzvf caffeine_2.6.2.tar.gz -C /path/to/preferred/dir
   ```
3. Test:

   ```
   cd /path/to/caffeine/dir
   ./bin/caffeine
   ```
4. Change startup executable on `/usr/share/applications/caffeine.desktop`

Answer (score 3):

As stated by @tomby, the GUI was removed in 2.7.

An option is download the 2.5 version [here](https://launchpad.net/~caffeine-developers/+archive/ppa/+files/caffeine_2.5_all.deb)

Install the required packages:

```
sudo apt-get install gir1.2-gtk-2.0 libsqlite0 python-kaa-base python-kaa-metadata python-sqlite
```

Then install the `.deb` file:

```
sudo dpkg -i caffeine_2.5_all.deb
```

Comment: This seems to me the best suggestion, it worked flawlessly.  Can't figure out why the developers went down that idiotic path, but so be it: it's their code, after all.

Comment: I totally agree, @Marco. Version 2.5 was a great, simple and perfect idea. Basically, [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @user10962 ! Your post help me to correct this issue. I definitively uninstall caffeine and replace it by a small script which is runned at startup. You must create before an empty file `/usr/sbin/pm-hibernate.gmev.sh` (with same right as pm-hibernate) and give rights in your sudoers file to your user to do `/bin/mv` and `/bin/cp` as root. It verifies (each minute) if vlc or flashplugin is used before disable screensaver (or blank screen) and hibernate :

```sh
#!/bin/sh
sudo /bin/mv /usr/sbin/pm-hibernate_unactived_by_gmev.sh /usr/sbin/pm-hibernate 2> /dev/null
while [ 1 ]
 do
  xset q | grep "DPMS is Disabled" > /dev/null
  rc=`echo $?`
  ps -ef | grep flashplugin | grep -v grep > /dev/null
  rc2=`echo $?`
  ps -ef | grep vlc | grep -v grep > /dev/null
  rc3=`echo $?`
  if  [ $rc2 -eq 0 ] || [ $rc3 -eq 0 ] 
   then
    if [ $rc -ne 0 ]
     then
      sudo /bin/mv /usr/sbin/pm-hibernate /usr/sbin/pm-hibernate_unactived_by_gmev.sh
      sudo /bin/cp -p /usr/sbin/pm-hibernate.gmev.sh /usr/sbin/pm-hibernate
      xset s off -dpms
     fi
   else
    if [ $rc -eq 0 ]
      then
      sudo /bin/mv /usr/sbin/pm-hibernate_unactived_by_gmev.sh /usr/sbin/pm-hibernate
      xset s on
      xset dpms 600 0 900
    fi
  fi
 sleep 60
done
```

Comment: Nice workaround, btw you can even check for player state (only while playing), See [How do I stop xscreensaver during movies play?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/445612/how-do-i-stop-xscreensaver-during-movies-play)

Comment: FWIW, you could just check for the existence of a 'flag' (say, /tmp/lock.disable) and have two scripts that toggle its existence.  This way, you can have a behavior similar to Caffeine (minus the handy icon/menu) and not just be limited to the couple of binaries you check for.

Answer (score 1):

This bugged me too so I've written a new caffeine application from scratch:

[image: Caffeine screenshot]

#### Installation

First make sure to remove [the other caffeine](https://launchpad.net/caffeine) if you have installed it:

```
sudo apt-get remove caffeine --purge
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:caffeine-developers/ppa
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:behda/ppa
```

Now you can install:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kzar/caffeine
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install caffeine
nohup caffeine &
```

Feedback + contributions welcome!
https://github.com/kzar/caffeine

Answer (score 0):

For those simply looking for a way to disable the default "sleep/suspend/hibernate after a given amount of time" routine (as is possible with the Caffeine applications on OSX and Windows), I found the following terminal commands do the trick nicely:

```bsh
# Turn off screensaver
xset s off
# Turn off sleep
xset s noblank
# Turn off suspend, hibernate, etc
xset -dpms
```

I recommend running these once and seeing if you like the result, then adding these to `.xinitrc` (or similar) so they're run by default at startup.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I've added a comment to [this bug](https://answers.launchpad.net/caffeine/+question/252722), I would recommend anyone else who is just as annoyed by the recent change to weigh in.

Who knows, we may get back the old, sane behavior :)

For now, as suggested by Rael, installing 2.5 seems to be the only solution.