# How can I change power settings automatically while running VLC in Xubuntu 14.04 64 bit

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, display, power-management, vlc

I am using `Xubuntu 14.04 64 bit`. I usually play video using `VLC media player`. The problem I am having is, `after 10 or 15 minutes computer turn off its display, even the video is running in the background`. To get back video I have to `move mouse` or `press any key` in my laptop. In xubuntu `default power settings` I do not see any option where I can prevent computer to sleep if media player in my computer is running. `Is there a way to set priority so that computer do not sleep when the video is running`. I attached current power setting of my computer.

[image]

Comment: Using the slider for Monitor, what happens if you move it all the way to the left?

Comment: but if i do that computer will not go to sleep even it is inactive for hours, see I want prevent the computer from idling only while video is playing, thank you for your reply :)

Comment: Perhaps someone with greater horsepower than I could suggest a shell script that runs when you start a video to reset the timers, and runs again when you stop the video to put the timers back.

Comment: can you tell me how to do that...

Comment: I would reformat your question to say something like "How can I change power settings automatically while running VLC" - I do not have enough programming experience to write an effective answer.  Include a tag for scripting, or shell-scripting

Comment: @rashedazad, you may try script in [How do I stop xscreensaver during movies play?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/445612/how-do-i-stop-xscreensaver-during-movies-play)