# Prevent monitor from losing signal after screen saver / lock activates

Tags: monitor, lock-screen, gnome-classic, gnome-screensaver

After the screen saver activates, or after I manually lock the screen via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, I see a blank black screen with just the date / time in the upper right corner. A few seconds after that, my HP flat screen monitor(s) lose the video signal and display ugly hopping "No Input Signal" boxes.

I'd like to keep the blank black screen (It's less distracting, consumes about as much power, and allows me to unlock faster, as the monitors don't have to re-sync), so Ubuntu should keep driving the video output while the screen is locked.

How can I configure this? I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS with the Gnome Classic Fall-back. Graphics card is NVIDIA with the open source Nouveau driver, but I also see this with an external HP NL571AA USB graphics adapter.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Ubuntu. It is probably part of the monitor's feature.

Comment: The operating system turns off the video signal; any monitor is then forced to react. Yes, this problem isn't limited to Ubuntu (but that's what I'm using), but I mostly see issues with other shared components (like Gnome, Firefox, etc.) discussed here as well, so I think it is on-topic.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

- This worked for me:

  ```
  xset -dpms
  ```

  The `-dpms` option disables DPMS (Energy Star) features.
- For permanent solution:

  ```
  echo "xset -dpms" >> ~/.xinitrc
  ```

  If it doesn't work or want more user friendly way,
  add `xset -dpms` to:

  System Tools → Preferences → Startup Applications

  (Thanks goes to [Ingo Karkat](https://askubuntu.com/users/72217/ingo-karkat))

**Reference:** `man xset`

Comment: Works for me, too. Thanks a lot; you've really earned the bounty with your persistence!

Comment: Note that the `~/.xinitrc` didn't work for me (using GNOME Classic); I instead put the `xset -dpms` into System Tools > Preferences > Startup Applications.

Comment: This worked for me as well on Ubuntu 16.04 with gdm3. Thank you!!

Comment: worked for me on ubuntu 18.04.3

Comment: worked for me on Ubuntu 19.10.

Comment: worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: This also helped me with OpenGL applications running on 1 FPS (or crashing right away) with the screen off (I use a simulator that combines on-screen and off-screen rendering, so it makes sense to run it with the screen turned off).